# Calculating joint density

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I am stuck on a problem, any clues/info are greatly appreciated.

The random variables $X$, $Y$, $Z$ have the following joint density:

$f_{X,Y,Z}(x,y,z) = c\hspace{2 mm}exp(-x -y -z) \hspace{10 mm} x > 0, y > 0, z > 0$

The problem is to find the density $\frac{1}{3}(X+Y+Z)$

I have no clues about this, so any help is, again, greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hint: if you can write the pdf as a product $u(x)v(y)w(z)$ then there is independence.

Comment: @drhab After some transformations I get stuck at trying to calculate the marginal density - I get undefined result

Comment: Why are there commas in that $\exp$ ?

Comment: @KurtG. my bad! - fixed it

Comment: Your task is to calculate first
$\mathbb P(\frac{X+Y+Z}{3}\le a)$ by solving a triple integral and then you differentiate that w.r.t $a\,.$

Comment: Hint: prove $X,\,Y \,Z$ are independent, each having characteristic function $1/(1-it)$.

Comment: Hint2: Note that $e^{-x}$ for $x>0$ and $0$ otherwise *is* a density.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A direct (albeit not easiest) calculation is as follows (note that $c=1$):

If $W$ is your random variable, then
\begin{align*}
F_W(a)&=\mathbb{P}(W\le a)=\iiint_A f_{X,Y,Z}(x,y,z)dxdydz
=\iiint_{x,y,z\ge 0;\ x+y+z\le 3a} e^{-x-y-z}dxdydz\\
&=\iint_{x,y\ge 0;\ x+y\le 3a} \left[e^{-x-y}-e^{-3a}\right]dxdy
=\iint_{x,y\ge 0;\ x+y\le 3a} \left[e^{-x-y}-e^{-3a}\right]dx
\\
&=\int_0^{3a}\left[e^{-x} - 3ae^{-3a} + xe^{-3a}- e^{-3a}\right]dx
=1 - \frac{(9a^2 + 6a + 2)e^{-3a}}2
\end{align*}
where $A=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3: x+y+z\le 3a\}$, so $f_W(a)=F_W(a)'=\frac{27}2 a^{3-1} e^{-3a}$ which is $\Gamma(3,3)$ distribution.